# Prepending unclosed tags in jQuery

Tags: jquery, append, prepend

Due to some limitations on the place files are being placed, I would like to prepend and append page structure just after the opening body tag and just before the closing body tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('body').prepend('<div id="header"><div id="title"></div></div><div id="wrapper"><div id="content">'); 
$('body').append('</div></div><div id="footer"></div>'); 
return false;  
});
</script>
```

My code does this, but it also closes all open div tags when using prepend. And append removes all tags that appear to be closing nothing.

Is this just a poor way to do what I am trying to do? Can I tell jQuery to stop "fixing" my html for me? Is the browser what is fixing my tags and not jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use .[wrapInner() for this](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/):

```
$(function() {
  $('body').wrapInner('<div id="wrapper"><div id="content"></div></div>');
  $('body').prepend('<div id="header"><div id="title"></div></div>'); 
  $('body').append('<div id="footer"></div>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I am just starting out with jQuery, this was a huge help.